# A filter is being applied to all of my sent emails, how do I stop that?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

A filter is being applied to all of my sent emails,  and causing them to be added to a folder they should not be in. How do I stop that?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to provide additional details. Is this happening to every sent message or just a lot of them. How many incoming mail filters do you currently have?  Did you apply any labels manually? If you switch off "conversation view" are the sent messages still in the wrong folders? Provide any additional context that can help us understand your problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Gmail, filters are applied to incoming messages, not outgoing / sent messages; however, some conditions might explain what you see.

The Gmail user settings are set to use the Conversation view by default. This group emails messages that meet some conditions together. On this view, the top message might look like it has a label, but the label might be applied to another message that belongs to the same conversation, like a reply that you received.